# Vapor with multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, query-string, vapor

I'm having trouble dealing with multiple parameters. I'm Ok with passing one, but am unsure about passing in multiple ones. I have this JS code in a webpage:

```
$.getJSON('api/vendor/countryVendors/'+country+'&'+resourceType,    function(result){}
```

And the following in my Vapor controller:

```
func getcountryVendors(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<[Vendor]> {
    let countryString = try req.parameters.next(String.self)
    let resourceTypeString = try req.parameters.next(String.self)
```

not sure if the URL I've created is wrong or my Swift code or both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to pass in [query-string parameters](https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/url-encoded-form/overview/#url-query), which are different from the [route path parameters](https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/getting-started/routing/#parameters). In this case, both snippets are wrong.

Query string parameters are key/value pairs that are appended to the end of a URL, like this:

```
/my/url/path?key=value&key1=value1
```

So your URL in your JS code should look like this:

```
'api/vendor/countryVendors?country='+country+'&resourceType='+resourceType
```

To get query string parameters from the URL passed in to the route handler, you use the `request.query` property and the `.get(_:at:)` method:

```
func getcountryVendors(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<[Vendor]> {
    let countryString = try req.query.get(String.self, at: "country")
    let resourceTypeString = try req.query.get(String.self, at: "resourceType") 

    // Other code...
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. I also needed to remove the String.parameter from the route. Than works perfectly.